# Querying suppression lists with WCF service

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, webservices

We are trying to use suppression lists to build a bespoke subscription centre. We need to be able to subscribe/unsubscribe users to particular categories of email which we send (i.e. *not* global unsubscribe).

The [code examples given in the documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_subscribers_on_a_list/) do not appear to work for suppression lists. A query to find all lists that a user is subscribed to returns publication lists but not the suppression lists.

Is there any way to get this working? If not, what other options do we have for building what we need?

We are aware of auto-suppression lists but as far as I can see from the documentation they do not offer the level of control to subscribe/unsubscribe independently to different email categories that we have.

Answer (score 2):

Our Team has a business need for this same functionality. After failing to get this working, we submitted the question to our customer liaison, and we were told it is not supported in the current version of the ExactTarget SOAP API.

Using the SOAP API, we can add and remove subscribers from suppression lists, but we cannot find out if the subscriber is already on a suppression list.